# How to generate the unsigned apk for android - reac-native

Tags: react-native

I tried to generate an unsigned apk to install on my other device.

I tried

```
cd android
```

then

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

I got an "app-release-unsigned.apk" at android\app\build\outputs\apk\release

I transfered this "app-release-unsigned.apk" to my other android device. Turned on the "install unknown apps". Then installed the "app-release-unsigned.apk", but I got error

```
App not installed.
```

Did I missed any steps? Why can't I install this app? I thought for a release, the apk should have everything it need to run my app.

Comment: why not trying gradlew assembleDebug?

Comment: It could be possible that you have an old debug version of the app already installed in your device. I have faced such situation. Please check and let us know if that works.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wvy8ACbP38I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and make sure you have created assets folder :

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res \
&& cd android \
&& ./gradlew clean\
&& ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

After this you can find your debug apk in

```
/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug
```

Hope it will work .

Comment: Thanks. This works. Is there any reason that we are creating an debug version and not an release unsigned app?

Comment: For release we have to make a keystore and release apk is used to deploy in play store .and simply if we want to debug our app go for debug apk only.